# How to change iterator of a function with multiprocessing by condition from inside of a process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to use next one iterator if my condition inside of a `Process` is triggered:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import requests
import os


def worker(url, data):
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, data=data, timeout=15)
        if r"Match" in response.text:
            print('Match!')
        if r"Wrong word" in response.text:
            print('Wrong word!')
            # CHANGE URL HERE
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


def init():
    # http://localhost:3000/set_phrase0\n http://localhost:3000/set_phrase1\n http://localhost:3000/set_phrase2\n...
    urls = open('urls.txt').read().splitlines()
    for url in urls:
        # if 'Wrong word' in response.text -> change url here and start with first file again
        for file in os.listdir('wordlists'):  # directory with generated words
            words = open(f'wordlists/{file}').read().splitlines()
            for word in words:
                data = {'word': word}
                Process(target=worker, args=(url, data)).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

Comment: I suggest you just use httpx with an asyncronous function for this task...

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Do you want to stop processing when you get a match? Also, as this isn't CPU-intensive you'd probably be better off multithreading

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to stop all processes associated with a URL if `"Wrong word"` is found in a response for that URL?

Comment: I don't get your exact use case, but this might be helpful:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes
Or this one, depending on what you'd like to achieve:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: @Axe319 you are understood me correctly

Comment: @Axe319 Its not necessary to stop 'em, its necessary to stop to call new Process'es associated with a URL if "Wrong word" and start new Process'es with next url

Comment: Can't you simply set a flag when "Wrong word" is found, and abort the loop when the flag is set? The use of multiprocessing might complicate that, but as already suggested, multithreading would probably be equally effective without this problems, and the links provided by Szellem contain solutions in case you want to keep using the multiprocessing library.